# Wrong string replacement in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, string, replace, str-replace

Using Javascript I have the following issue, when displaying data on a web page.

The code goes like this:

```
myString.replace('\n', '<br/>');
```

I suppose the purpose is clear, I want to replace the '\n' linefeed marker by the *< br / >* tag, doing the same thing but in HTML.

The problem is:

Starting with the string: *abc\nXYZ* instead of getting *abc< br />XYZ* like I would expect, I end up with *abc & lt;br/& gt;XYZ*. This is of course not what I want, because the effect is not the same.

What is the proper work around?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: `"abc\nXYZ".replace('\n', '<br/>');` gives me `"abc<br/>XYZ"` when I log the result in the console. Why do you think you get `abc & lt;br/& gt;XYZ` ? Are you doing anything else after?

Comment: I suppose this is because your console interpretes &lt; as < and &gt; as >. I also get this on my web page, but if I look in the source of the page I see abc&lt;br/&gt;XYZ. I should see abc<br/>XYZ in the source and a jump to the next line in the web page.

Comment: javascript do not treat `<` differently AFAIK, so it should not get `&lt`.

Comment: @Ashraf This is not a duplicate. String replacement works fine. The issue here is about the special handling of the characters < and >.

Comment: @apple apple I am working with Node.js and express. Could that be the issue.

Comment: @Michel the problem was with escaping the backslash.

Comment: @Michel not sure about express, but if it convert `<` to `&lt`.  I think it would also convert `\n` to `<br/>`. so this conversion may not be needed at all.

Comment: Added the correct answer @Michel . Maybe you weren't finishing the function properly.

Comment: No unfortunately the`\n` is not converted to `<br/>`.

Comment: Must be browser problem then, works for me

Answer (score 0):

Get the inner HTML and then `str.replace("\n", "<br/>")` and put it back into the inner HTML. I've attached a code snippet of the working demo.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
  var res = str.replace("\n", "<br/>");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <p>Click the button to replace carriage returns with line-break in the paragraph below:</p>

  <p id="demo">Visit 
  Stack Overflow!</p>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: OP is using substring matching, not regex matching. and does not mentioning any global matching problem.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. Made the required adjustments. @appleapple

Comment: Using: myString.replace("\\n", "<br/>") does not work. I tried it. It puts a jump to the next line in the source of the page, but no jump in the page itself. I want the jump to happen on the page.

Comment: @Michel I didn't exactly understand what "jump on the page itself" meant, could you please explain what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: To replace newlines (which would only be there in the source, not on the rendered page) with `<br/> ` tags that would put a line break in the actual page. Replacing `"\\n"` will NOT catch new lines - it would catch the literal sequence `\n` so a text where the *content* is, say `previous\next` (a string literal of `"previous\\next"`) will be turned into `previous<br/>ext` because the real to represent a new line is via the string literal sequence `"\n"` which then gets turned into a new line. If you do `myString = "line1\nline2"` and then try your proposal, you'd see it doesn't work.

Comment: It means go to the next line. Like when you use "<br/>" in some of your HTML code. I am trying to replace "\n" by "<br/>" so that when displayed on the web page it produces a line break.

Comment: Understood the question, sorry for the wrong answer.

Comment: Thanks for the snippet, but I do not want to click a button. I found it finally  simpler to deal with it using express/ejs.

Comment: Not a problem, glad I could help somewhat

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the `\n` is being replaced by the **string** version of the `<br/>` tag, meaning, the way HTML translates it so that `<` and `>` show up instead of functioning as a tag.

What you should do is obtain the HTML and replace the section within that. Something like this:

```
var myDiv = Document.getElementById('my-div');
var myDivContent = myDiv.innerHTML;
myDiv.innerHTML = myDivContent.replace("\\n", "<br/>");
```

Comment: This solution though more complicated than I would like, I am willing to try it but when I try I get this error: "Document is not defined". What should I do? I am using express with node.js.

Comment: Oh, so you're using `Node JS`, so back end javascript. The `Document` is part of the DOM, so it won't work in this case.  How exactly are you returning this string to the client?

Comment: I gave up challenging this path. It is much easier to just handle the problem using express. Just cutting the string into pieces.